# open-source JavaScript onclick tooltip solution required

Tags: javascript, open-source, xhtml, tooltip

I've been searching for a long time now for a fairly simple JavaScript based tooltip solution. It needs to be:

- Open-Source and freely re-distributable, and allows my application to include it which would be distributable via free or commercial license.
- 'Sticky' i.e when opened it stays visible until the user clicks a little close button on it or ESC button is pressed.
- Style-able via CSS (preferably) or JavaScript.
- Compatible with IE6 or IE7 onwards, as well as modern browsers ;)

I did manage to find http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/ (see the buttons example on that page) which meets all the requirements - except that I wouldn't be able to distribute what I'm creating for free which makes it a no-go :(

It only needs to able to handle basic HTML (div, p, span, img, etc) within the tooltip.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I've seen a lot of jQuery tooltips out there, but none that I can remember that won't disappear on mouseoff by default.  Might still be worth while searching for jQuery instead of Javascript though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/) a jQuery based opensource tooltip plugin, you can control the events when to show the tip. for example `show: { when: { event: 'click' } }` this will show the tooltip on click on the target element. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Teja, that's perfect for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a tooltip that also works without a library (like jQuery) you can use [Opentip](http://www.opentip.org) which uses adapters for all major frameworks, and provides a native adapter that doesn't need a framework.

It's open source and MIT licensed.